# How to configure apache server for sending a 301 code in response

Tags: linux, apache

I want to  to configure Apache for moved permanently response.

What ever idea I have about this  is --

1) I need to add below line in httpaccess 
Redirect 301 /e/301
         Can I put this line any where in httpaccess file?

2) then I have to have a page (say it is redirect.html, ) put in
 /var/www/html/project_name.

Which will be displayed on redirection(will show 301 code).

Now  what I want is, if someone access the page example.html, it need to be redirected to redirect.html .

Where and what syntax I need  to add or what changes need to be done in httpd or other different Apache files.

Please correct me if I am wrong in above two points.

Thanks alot.

Comment: This sounds like abuse of the 301 response code. If you mean to indicate an error condition then you should use a 4xx response code.

Answer (score 1):

Got  a solution-
 We can do it be using Redirection directory or by re-write engine  in httpdaccess.conf

for doing this  by re-write engine  add below line in conf file

RewriteEngine On

### for 302 code

RewriteRule /.* http://www.new_server.com/ [R]

### for 301 - permanent redirecting the your side to another one

RewriteRule permanent  /.* http://www.new_server.com/ [R]

#### for page

## Redirect /old.html http://ww.new_server.com/new.html

Redirect permanent /old.html http://www.new_server.com/new.html